# Extracting the numbers in the 5th column only from a text file

Tags: matlab

I got a .txt file which has 82332 rows and 5 columns. I only want to extract the numbers from the 5th column to a vector. Is this possible in Matlab?

The text file looks like this.
1.0000000e+00   6.0205125e+01  -1.1923175e+02   3.5341908e+02   3.7197225e-01

Any hints or tips appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `textscan` you can specify to ignore fields (columns) with the `*` modifier to the format specification.

```
fid = fopen('test_data.txt','r');
C = textscan(fid,'%*f%*f%*f%*f%f');
fclose(fid)
```

Your vector is `C{1}`. NOTE: If there are trailing columns to ignore, you can just skip the remainder of the line with `%*[^\n]`.

---

You can also use `dlmread` with the `range` input argument *if* you know the number of rows in the file:

```
col = 5; numRows = 24;
dlmread('test_data.txt','',[1 col numRows col] - 1)
```